# Can I limit an assume rule policy to a specific lambda, instead of lambda's in general?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I'm trying to get into the whole IAM setup. I have a role that I want a lambda to be able to assume.
So, I have my Trust Relationship policy setup like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, as far as I understand, this would allow any lambda to assume this role.
Can I narrow this in a bit more, so it's only one specific lambda, that is allowed to assume it?

I've tried to replace `"Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"` with the arn of the lambda, but it didn't really work out for me :/

Comment: I'm not sure AWS allows Resource level permission for this, but the way to go about this would be to add `"Resource": <Lambda ARN>` under Action

Comment: @NinadGaikwad No, resource constraints aren't supported in Role Trust Policies, regardless of what will assume them.  The "correct" way would be to use an `aws:SourceArn` constraint, but AWS inexplicably doesn't support that for Lambda.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45806907/how-to-make-a-role-assumable-by-given-lambda-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it's actually the other way around...

When creating the Lambda function, you can specify the role for it to use. The **ability to allow a function to use a Role** requires the `iam:PassRole` permission. Anyone with this permission can configure a Lambda function to use a specific (or any) IAM Role.

Here's a sample policy from [Granting a User Permissions to Pass a Role to an AWS Service - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_passrole.html) that grants an IAM User the ability to pass a role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:GetRole",
            "iam:PassRole"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/EC2-roles-for-XYZ-*"
    }]
}
```

`iam:PassRole` is a very important permission because it controls who can pass a role to a service. Used incorrectly, users might gain too much permission. For example, let's say that there is an Admin Role that has lots of permissions. Anyone who is granted permission to use `PassRole` could create a resource (eg Amazon EC2 instance or AWS Lambda function) that uses this role, thereby giving them Admin capabilities. For this reason, the ability to use `PassRole` should be strictly controlled.

Therefore, rather than the role trusting a Lambda function, you actually need a user with `PassRole` to assign the role to the function.